# Incompatible shapes error in tensorflow when loss function changed

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function

I have a model which I  train through an auto-encoder.  To start with, I used for my loss function the binary cross_entropy.  Everything works well.  I wanted to try a different loss function, the sigmoid-focal cross_entropy.  When I use this, I get an "incompatible shapes" error.

Here is the relevant code, and as can be seen the output for either loss has the same shape.  Nothing else in the code has changed:

relevant code:

```
loss0 = binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits) 
loss1 = tf.reduce_mean(alpha_factor * modulating_factor * loss0, axis=-1)
print('^&^&^&^&^&^&^ loss0',loss0)
print('^&^&^&^&^&^&^ loss1',loss1)
.
.
.

autoencoder.compile(optimizer=optim, loss=loss1, metrics=['accuracy','AUC'])
```

Output:

```
^&^&^&^&^&^&^ loss0 Tensor("ww_loss/Mean_2:0", shape=(None, 300, 300), dtype=float32)

^&^&^&^&^&^&^ loss1 Tensor("ww_loss/Mean_3:0", shape=(None, 300, 300), dtype=float32)


InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [32,300,300,1] vs. [32,300,300]
     [[node gradient_tape/ww_loss/mul_7/BroadcastGradientArgs
```

When loss0 is used, there is no error.  I am a bit stymied!

Comment: I apologize, in the code, the definition of loss1 should have loss0 instead of ce:
loss0 = binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits) 
loss1 = tf.reduce_mean(alpha_factor * modulating_factor * loss0, axis=-1)

Comment: you can edit  your question and correct it

Comment: Have you tried   setting the parameter `keepdims=True` when calling `tf.reduce_mean` ?